# Get a Number from String with no default decimal separator

Tags: apache-flex, localization, numbers, decimal, flex4.5

I have a `TextInput` where a need to return a `Number`.
My problem is that entered value is localized to a logged in user and that effects the *decimal separator*. 
I seem to always get a `NaN` when i try to get a Number from a Polish user but it works great for English users:

Input example:
English: 23.5
Polish: 23,5

Is there a workaround for this? I have the following that doesn't work:

```
public function get myValue():Number {
    var value:Number = new Number(StringUtil.trim(text)); //NaN with Polish
    return value;
}
```

I have also tried the following but it also gives a `NaN`:

```
private function myValue(number:Number, precision:Number=2):Number{
    var numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = getNumberFormatter(precision);
    return new Number(numberFormatter.formatNumber(number));
}

private function getNumberFormatter(precision:Number=2):NumberFormatter{
    var iso:String = ClientInfo.instance.language.ISOCode;
    var formattedIso:String = iso.substr(0, 2)+'_'+iso.substr(2,2);
    var numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(formattedIso);
    numberFormatter.fractionalDigits = precision;
    numberFormatter.trailingZeros = true;
    return numberFormatter;
}
```

When I debug the code I can see that the `NumberFormatter` works correctly but its always the call to `new Number("23,5")` that gives a `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it now, but I guess it should work:

```
public function get myValue():Number 
{
    var value:Number = getNumberFormatter.parseNumber(StringUtil.trim(text));
    return value;
}
```

I think the key is, that you should use [parseNumber()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html#parseNumber%28%29)!

**[Update]**
Here is a FlexUnit test for better understanding:

```
[Test]
public function test(): void
{
    var number: Number = new NumberFormatter("de-DE").parseNumber("23,5");
    assertEquals(23.5, number);

    number = new NumberFormatter("en-US").parseNumber("23.5");
    assertEquals(23.5, number);

    number = new NumberFormatter("de-DE").parseNumber("1.023,456");
    assertEquals(1023.456, number);

    number = new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("1023,45");
    assertEquals(1023.45, number);

    number = new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("1.023,45");
    assertTrue(isNaN(number));

    number = new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("1 023,45");
    assertEquals(1023.45, number);

    number = new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("  10 531 023,45  ");
    assertEquals(10531023.45, number);
}
```

As you can see `NumberFormatter` handles decimal and thousands separator correctly.

If you want to format it back, then you could use it like this:

```
var numFmt: NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter("pl-PL");
assertEquals("23,50", numFmt.formatNumber(numFmt.parseNumber("  23,5  ")));
numFmt.fractionalDigits = 1;
assertEquals("23,6", numFmt.formatNumber(numFmt.parseNumber("  23,57  ")));
```

Comment: The parseNumber only returns string so I do not belive this will work. I have tried to use it with a new Number(..parseNumber(text)) and it still gives NaN

Comment: @Marthin [parseNumber()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html#parseNumber%28%29) returns per definition a `Number`!

Comment: You are correct. In my IDE it says return type String but itw wrong =). Thx for the help

Comment: This is all great and it solves my question but not my problem because in the end i will need something that can handle assert(23,5, number) where number is new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("23,5"); I need this for my validator

Comment: @Marthin Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. This should definitly work: `assertEquals(23.5, new NumberFormatter("pl-PL").parseNumber("23,5"));`

Comment: Yes you are right that works, but i need to compare with a "Polish" number as you can in my comment i assert with a ',' not a '.'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers are not being returned with commas between each 10^3 number group (i.e. 1,000,000 for 1 million), you could just use a replace on the commas.

```
Number("23,5".replace(",","."); // output Number( "23.5" ) = 23.5
```

That will replace all commas in the number with a period and should be read as a normal number by the system.